# How do i pull fields from a channel with a category_group tagged, but only the category tag that is checked

Tags: categories

I've searched for solutions on how to display the selected category, to no avail.

I need to display entries that has that category field selected within that channel

This code just opens the channel needed thats tagged with that category group.
But if i select fields within that channel it gives me all, unchecked and checked category items.

`{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" dynamic="no" category_group="category_id"} {/exp:channel:entries}`

Answer (score 0):

Using your code example are you trying to output one entry from a specific category *group*?

If so some if your syntax may need adjusting, you don't usually have curly braces as parameter values.

This example will show one entry from your_channel_name with category group ID 1:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="your_channel_name" dynamic="no" limit="1 category_group="1"}
{title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Hi Bluedreamer, thats correct yes, i just used the curly braces fr example purposes.

So I've got a category with two items stored. E.g. Location and Experience.
What I need to do is display all entries within that category group, that is only selected with Location category item. Does that make sense?

Comment: So are "Location" and "Experience" channel entries, or categories?

Comment: They are categories

Comment: So for example, "Destination" channel has a category called "Destination Types". And within the category Destination Types, there are "locations" & "months". Some destination entries are marked with "locations" and others with "months". What i need is to only display those destination entries marked with "locations". Sorry if im not making much sense, I know EE, but not too well.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your exact setup it's worth trying the category parameter:

In this example it will only show entries that have been assigned to category ID 1 *and* 5

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="your_channel_name" dynamic="no" limit="1 category="1&5"}
{title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example.

This is my exact code I have right now, in the embed template.  
`{exp:channel:entries  channel="destination_info" category="9" limit="3" search:destination_parent="{embed:parent_id}"}
{title}{/exp:channel:entries}`

Comment: And within the template I want it to show, `{embed="channel_group/template_name" parent_id="{entry_id}"}`, but for some reason, nothing shows. Think I'm not connecting it properly. Once I get the entries to show that is within that channel, under that category. Then I need to only show the entries that is tagged with the 'Locale' category name.

Comment: Hmm that's a bit of a head scratcher, hard to diagnose without seeing *everything* that's going on. What I'd suggest is setting up a working copy of the site then letting an EE pro login to see what's happening.

Comment: I'm sorted, I was missing the category_id tag within my channel entries tag. 
Thanx for trying to help, appreciate it. :)

Comment: Oh well found, glad you got it sorted.